# inotify,inotify_add_watch() to monitor multiple directories, c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, inotify

Am using [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and [INOTIFY_ADD_WATCH()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html) to monitor activities on multiple directories. Is it possible to add multiple file paths(directories) using a loop. i have have the following sample code, but am not receiving any notification.

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{

    //---------------------------------------------------
    vector<string> sensitive_dir_path;//a vector to store file path(directory)
    const int max_chars_per_line=200000;
    ifstream fin("secure_file_path.txt");//file containing file paths
    if(!fin.good())
    {
        cout<<"File not found: [file name: 'secure_file_path.txt' not found: "<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    while(!fin.eof())//open file and push the lines to a vector
    {
        char buf[max_chars_per_line];
        fin.getline(buf, max_chars_per_line);
        string str(buf);

        if(str.compare("")== 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        else
        {
            sensitive_dir_path.push_back(str);
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------
    int length, i = 0;
    int fd;
    int wd[sensitive_dir_path.size()];
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    fd = inotify_init();

    if ( fd < 0 ) 
    {
        perror( "inotify_init" );
    }
    for(int index=0;index<sensitive_dir_path.size();index++)
    {
        string new_path=sensitive_dir_path[index];
        char* fam_sensitive_dir_path=new char[new_path.length()];
        strcpy(fam_sensitive_dir_path,new_path.c_str());

        wd[index] = inotify_add_watch( fd,fam_sensitive_dir_path, IN_CREATE);
        //cout<<"path: "<<fam_sensitive_dir_path<<"  will be monitored\n";
    }

    while (1)
    {
        struct inotify_event *event;
        length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  

        if ( length < 0 ) 
        {
            perror( "read" );
        } 

        event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];

        if ( event->len ) 
        {       
            if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE )
            {
                if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) 
                {
                    printf( "The directory %s was created.\n", event->name );       
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf( "The file %s was created.\n", event->name );
                }
            }
        }
    }
for(int index=0;index<sensitive_dir_path.size();index++)//
{
    ( void ) inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd[index] );
}
    ( void ) close( fd );

    exit( 0 );
}
```

file to read:

- secure_file_path.txt

"/home/Dir-one"

"/home/Dir-two"

"/home/Dir-three"
.
.
.

or any alternative option to add multi-directories?

Comment: You're missing a `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive multiple events in the buffer, but your code is only looking at the first one.

You should change your loop to be more like this:

```
while (1) {
    struct inotify_event *event, *end;
    length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);  

    if (length < 0) {
        perror( "read" );
        break;
    }

    // Our current event pointer
    event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[0];
    // an end pointer so that we know when to stop looping below
    end = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[length];

    while (event < end) {
        // Do your printing or whatever here
        printf("name is %s\n", event->name);

        // Now move to the next event
        event = (struct inotify_event *)((char*)event) + sizeof(*event) + event->len;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello@wez-furlong, thank you for your answer, it is helpful. but still i get a problem/error on the line to move to the next event, i.e in          (event = ((char*)event) + sizeof(*event) + event->len;)  it says:      error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘inotify_event*’ in assignment.